# Call a Form / Module with a variable VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to call a Form with a variable.  So instead of the following code:

```
Form1.TextBox.value = 1
Form2.TextBox.value = 1
Form3.TextBox.value = 1
```

I would replace Form1, Form2, and Form3 with a variable **FormName**

```
Dim FormName as Variant

If number=1 then FormName="Form1"
If number=2 then FormName="Form2"
If number=3 then FormName="Form3"

FormName.TextBox.value = 1
```

But I can't figure out how to call a module/form with a variable.  Please assist. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not something like this:

```
Dim Form As UserForm

If Number = 1 Then Set Form = Form1
If Number = 2 Then Set Form = Form2
If Number = 3 Then Set Form = Form3

Form.TextBox.Value = 1
```